# In jersey 2.x filter implementation does not work?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

While i am trying to add response header by implementing ContainerResponseFilter.but it does not work.

Java code :-

```
public class PoweredByResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
        ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
}

 }
```

Deployment descriptor :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Filters</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classes</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jersey.filter.PoweredByResponseFilter,org.jersey.filter.AuthorizationRequestFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

Response header :-

[image]

New descriptor :-

```
i change my descriptor to                                                                            <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the init-param name wrong. This

```
jersey.config.server.provider.classes
```

should be

```
jersey.config.server.provider.classnames
```

See [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.13/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES).

Another thing you could've done is simply annotate the filter class with `@Provider`. As long as the class is in the package (or sub-package) listed in `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`, it will be picked up and automatically registered.

For example if the filter is annotated with `@Provider` it is in the `org.jersey` or `org.jersey.filters` or `org.jersey.foo.filters`, be default it will be picked up and registered. This way you don't need to explicitly list it in the xml configuration.

Comment: @Mr.peeskillet Now also header does not add with response

Comment: What did you change? If you made the change above, it _should_ work. Both options I provided should work.

Comment: i change my descriptor to                                                                <servlet><servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>                                                                                                            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class><init-param>
   <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>org.jersey</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: You completely removed the param. My answer says to change it. Or the second option is to simply annotate the filter class with `@Provider`

Comment: There's no reason I can think of that it should not work if the filter is in the `org.jersey` package or a sub-package. And you correctly annotated the class.

Comment: @Provider
public class CheckRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter .like that i annotated. and it belongs to org.jersey.filter package

Comment: Why are you showing a `ClientRequestFilter` when your question is about a `ContainerResponseFilter`? Those are two different things. The former is used only on the client side. It which case you need to register it with the `Client`

Comment: sorry i am using both filters, is ClientRequestFilter only on client side? the ContainerResponseFilter aslo i am using same @Provider annotation

Comment: Yes `ClientXxxFilter` should only be used on the client side and `ContainerXxxFilter` only on server. For the client you can register like `client.register(Filter.class)`

Comment: is ContainerResponseFilter loads at when jersey container is starting? but still it does not work for me .still i am doing some mistake

Comment: Add a print statement in the constructor to see if it is created

Comment: constructor print statement , ContainerResponseFilter object created ,but given header does not add to the response.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to tell you then. It works fine for me.